# Wordpress Won't Display Letters "FI"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is an odd one. I noticed it when I added the Contact Form 7 plugin. When the form is submitted with errors, the notification would read "required   elds" The "fi" was not displayed, even though it's present in the HTML when I inspect element. I noticed the same thing on my category archives, which display in a category description. In the description, the letters "fi" will not display.

To be clear, it's only when the letters "fi" are next to one another. It'll output the letter "f" and the letter "i" individually, but words like "find" just come out as "  ind" The letters occupy space on the screen, but they won't display.

This is probably a super noob question, and I'll probably feel silly later on or being stumped, but I'm tearing my hair out at the moment.

I'm creating my own theme from scratch, if that's useful info. And "fi" shows up fine in the body of an article.

Comment: there is nothing we can help you. minimun what you should to provide is your website url

Comment: try switching a theme, and let us know if you still have the issue